# BigQuery - Subtracting days in one column from dates in another column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following table (call it TABLE_A) in BigQuery with 2 columns:

| start_date | prep_days |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-01-12 | 10 |
| 2024-03-28 | 3 |

I'd like to create a new column called `prep_date` which contains new dates by subtracting `prep_days` from `start_date`. I would like the following table result:

| start_date | prep_days | prep_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-12 | 10 | 2024-01-02 |
| 2024-03-28 | 3 | 2024-03-25 |

The [DATE_SUB](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_sub) function in BigQuery seems to only allow a fixed interval to subtract dates with. Are there other methods that can achieve my goal shown above?

I've attempted to use the DATE_SUB function to subtract `prep_days` from `start_date` by using the following:

```sql
SELECT
    START_DATE,
    PREP_DAYS,
    DATE_SUB(START_DATE, INTERVAL PREP_DAYS DAY) AS PREP_DATE
FROM TABLE_A
```

but the following error is thrown:
`Interval value must be coercible to INT64 type at [29:45]`

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work. However, the column `prep_days` is not a whole integer. Therefore, please convert it to int64 by using `safe_cast`.

```
WITH
  TABLE_A AS (
  SELECT
    date "2024-01-12" AS START_DATE,
    10.0 prep_days
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    date "2024-03-28",
    3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    CURRENT_DATE(),
    NULL )
    
SELECT
  START_DATE,
  PREP_DAYS,
  DATE_SUB(START_DATE, INTERVAL SAFE_CAST(PREP_DAYS AS INT64) DAY) AS PREP_DATE
FROM
  TABLE_A
```